# how to post data using JSON for httpPost in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an example json as below:

{
    "Passwd":"String content",
    "Userme":"String content"
}

how to construct the JSON String as above and  give it as argument to  HttpPost in Android.?

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue. 
thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `JSONObject` to create a simple json like `{ "Passwd":"String content", "Userme":"String content" }` try something like this.

```
            String json="";
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
            jobj.put("Userme", "Username");
            jobj.put("Passwd", "PasswordValue");
            json = jobj.toString();
```

Above String can be sent as one of the parameter using HTTP POST easily. Below function takes url and json as parameters to make POST request.

```
private void httpPost(String json,String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json));
      httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
      httpClient.execute(httpPost);
  }
```

Comment: Hi I have a JSON like the below which do not contain key         : {"String content"}. Then in this case how to create JSON as it donot contain KEY.